# C++: Which floating-point operations, if any, are guaranteed by the standard to be non-throwing?

Tags: c++, exception, floating-point, c++20, nothrow

In C++20 (or later), are there any operations involving floating point numbers that are guaranteed by the standard to never throw?

What about

1. assignment and copy construction?
2. comparison?
3. arithmetic?

**Note**, I am concerned here only with ordinary regular C++ exceptions, not the special notion of "floating-point exceptions".

Here is a more precise formulation of my question:

If `a` and `b` are mutable objects of type `double`, which of the following expressions, if any, are guaranteed by the C++ standard to evaluate to true?

1. `noexcept(a = b)`
2. `noexcept(a == b)`
3. `noexcept(a + b)`

For new readers, I'd like to clarify that I am only interested in "defined behavior", that is, everything that is not undefined behavior.

Comment: _"...The floating-point exceptions are __not__ related to the C++ exceptions. When a floating-point operation raises a floating-point exception, the status of the floating-point environment changes, which can be tested with std::fetestexcept, but the execution of a C++ program on most implementations continues uninterrupted...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv

Comment: @RichardCritten, good point. I am interested only in whether these operations can throw ordinary regular C++ exceptions. I'll make an edit to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: floating point numbers, `float`, `double`, and `long double` are low-level primatives. They don't really have constructors, and the basic built-in operators for them do not throw exceptions of the C++ variety.

Comment: @user4581301 That seems right to me, but is it mandated by the C++ standard, or just the case in practice?

Comment: @KristianSpangsege The results of the operations are described in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/#expr.  As long as the section doesn't say an exception will be thrown then wont be.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok, maybe you are right. But that is a very implicit result. It would be nice with a more explicit statement. I don't expect there to be one, as I have never found one while looking, but I am curious what knowledgeable people can say about it. Maybe it is explicitly stated somewhere, or strictly implied by something elsewhere in the standard.

Comment: Also worth reading [MATH_ERRNO, MATH_ERREXCEPT, math_errhandling](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling)

Comment: @KristianSpangsege I've never seen something and I've read pretty much the entire thing a few times.  C++ was designed to run on a wide range of hardware and some of that might not be able to notice an arithmetic exception.  By just saying the result is UB it allows a lot of freedom the the implementation.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair point. I'll let the question stand for a while to see if somebody has something more definitive to say about it.

Comment: [Constructors are special member functions](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#special-1). This means they are part of a class. [Fundamental types are not classes](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-1) because [classes are a compound type](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-1.5). If it's not explicitly forbidden by the standard you should assume that some lunatic will try it, so out there someone probably has made a compiler that generates exceptions on arithmetic operations just to see if they could. It's not something you can expect to see in the wild, though.

Comment: Side note: In C++23 you get extended floating point types, but  I'm still chewing on C++17, so it'll be a while before I get there.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, that does make sense to me. I did expect the answer to be that the standard does not guarantee any of this, but I wanted to be sure I hadn't missed something :-)

Comment: Yeah, all I can conclusively eliminate is you don't have to worry about constructors throwing because there aren't any.

Comment: While we are at it, my understanding has always been that for fundamental **integer** types, the standard does mandate that assignment, comparison, and arithmetic (maybe excluding division) is non-throwing. You agree?

Comment: As with floating point types if you put in garbage you get UB out.

Comment: Yeah, ok, but then if we exclude UB from the question, then they are non-throwing, right?

Comment: What should happen when you add two conforming numbers shouldn't have to be specified by the C++ Standard. But like I said, there are lunatics out there.

Comment: @user4581301 I realize that I have somewhat derailed this discussion by not being clear from the beginning that I was only interesting in non-UB behavior. It seems to me that you guys are generally claiming that outside of UB, the standard does not allow for exceptions to be thrown, not for floating point types, and also not for integer types. Is that also how you see it?

Comment: An explicit rule could be buried in there somewhere, the Standard's a big mother, but an operation performing as expected is hardly exceptional enough to throw an exception. Basic arithmetic doesn't have many points that you can consider exceptional, and those have already been called out as UB. That leaves bad math on the part of the programmer, and it's the programmer's job to either get that right or implement their own specialized protections to make sure they do (bounds checks, etc...)

Comment: @user4581301   The extended floating point support in C++23 is (roughly speaking) the introduction of optional fixed size types like `float32_t`  i.e. floating point counterparts of types from earlier standards like `int32_t`.    These are optional (as are the fixed width integral types) and conditional on the implementation supporting ISO 60559.  If supported, they are primitive types, and operations on them don't throw C++ exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Note 1](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#note-1) An exception can be thrown from one of the following contexts: throw-expressions ([expr.throw](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.throw)), allocation functions ([basic.stc.dynamic.allocation](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation)), dynamic_cast ([expr.dynamic.cast](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.dynamic.cast)), typeid ([expr.typeid](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid)), new-expressions ([expr.new](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new)), and standard library functions ([structure.specifications](https://eel.is/c++draft/structure.specifications)).

Floating point operators are none of those.

Notes are not normative, but they are good enough for me.

Comment: Yes, I think this is true. We can add that C standard library functions cannot throw, and that also comes very close to implying that fundamental floating-point operations cannot throw. I am willing to mark this as the correct answer. But to any readers, be sure to also see the other answers and comments, as they add relevant considerations.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to note  that *floating point exception* refers to exceptions such as `FE_DIVBYZERO` or `FE_INEXACT` defined in [`<cfenv>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfenv). These are not exceptions in the `std::exception` sense, but flags in the floating point environment which can be checked using [`std::fexceptflag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feexceptflag).

#### Exceptions could be thrown as the result of undefined behavior

That being said, floating point operations *could in principle* throw regular exceptions:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.
>
> [*Note*: Treatment of division by zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all floating-point exceptions varies among machines, and is sometimes adjustable by a library function.
> — *end note*]

- [[expr.pre] p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre#4)

This paragraph could come into action when a floating point operation produces an undefined result.
Division by zero is generally undefined behavior in C++, and no exception is made for floating point numbers, not even when [`std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) is `true`.

The implementation could choose to throw an exception when division by zero is performed simply because division by zero is UB, and so the implementation can do anything it wants then.
This is one of the reasons why functions with narrow contracts (see [Lakos Rule](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2861r0.pdf)) aren't marked `noexcept`, even those from the C standard library, which otherwise cannot throw (see [[res.on.exception.handling] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.exception.handling#2)).

#### `noexept(...)` is `true` for floating point operations regardless

> 1. `noexcept(a = b)`
> 2. `noexcept(a == b)`
> 3. `noexcept(a + b)`

Also, all of these are guaranteed to be `true` because the `noexcept` operator only considers whether an exception is [potentially throwing](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#def:potentially-throwing,expression). It does not consider whether an exception could be thrown as the result of undefined behavior.

Equality comparison (see [[expr.eq]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#6)) and assignment (see [[expr.ass]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass)) are never UB, and so they cannot even throw by that means (unless uninitialized values are used). See [[except.throw] Note1](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.throw#note-1) for a list of expressions that can throw under normal circumstances.

#### Conclusion

Floating point exceptions are different from regular exceptions; they only have the name in common. It is *theoretically* possible that traditional exceptions are thrown when floating point operations run into UB, although no compiler does this in practice.

Comment: Ok, so if I take your last statement seriously, then the standard must allow for exceptions to be thrown at least in divisions. I would love to see somebody else corroborate this understanding. Also, what about assignment and comparison, can they also generate "floating-point exceptions"?

Comment: Are you just talking about division _of zero_ by zero?  Most division by zero is well-defined in IEC 559 environment, yielding ±∞.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, there are some wording issues though: [see expr.mul](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4). Division by zero is UB in principle (and `float` is not exempt in any way), although all compilers choose to treat it normally in the IEC 559 way. This could be seen as a compiler extension, and it is *theoretically* possible that compilers could throw an exception instead.

Comment: @JanSchultke Did you mean to say that the `noexcept(...)` expressions are necessarily `true`? It seem to me that you are arguing that they would be `true` on most platforms, but there could be a platform where they trow, so they must be `false`. What am I missing?

Comment: @KristianSpangsege `noexcept(a + b)` is `true` because it checks whether an exception is potentially throwing, which is a very specific requirement. It is possible that `a + b` throws an exception even though `noexcept(a + b)` is `true`, but only if this exception is thrown as the result of UB, which is not considered by the `noexcept` operator.

Comment: @JanSchultke Alright. I see your point. So you are making the point that if we exclude UB from our consideration, then non-throwing behavior is strictly guaranteed by the standard. My next question would then be, is there any room for UB in fp assignment and comparisons?

Comment: @KristianSpangsege no. Assignment and comparison in the standard basically just talk about assigning *some value* and checking *if values are equal*, and there is no room for this to be UB assuming both sides of the operator have a value (i.e. neither is uninitialized). If there is UB, it's the result of doing something else wrong, like dividing by zero, or dereferencing a null `float*`.

Comment: @JanSchultke Ok, that rhymes a lot with my understanding. The upshot, I guess, is that fp assignment and comparison is definitely non-throwing regardless of whether we include UB in our discussion.

Comment: Re. assignment. Floats are "trivial types" (section [basic.types]). Trivial defaulted copy ctors/assignment operators are `noexcept`. I think this rules out exceptions for on any assignment. Note also: Section [res.on.exception.handling]: "Functions from the C standard library shall not throw exceptions". That includes cmath. You cannot really implement math.h without exceptions if your floats throw exceptions, right?

Comment: @KristianSpangsege *"whether we include UB in our discussion"* It is generally implied that any statement about C++ has an unspoken trailing "[...], unless you are in UB". It is a little bit redundant to explicitly exclude UB from the discussion.

Comment: @Homer512 I think you're right. However, the functions in `<cmath>` are not marked `noexcept`, though I'm not sure what the reason is. I suppose that if UB like division by zero happens inside a `<cmath>` function, then it would still be allowed to throw in spite of the requirements for math functions that normally exist because UB trumps everything. However, that doesn't seem like a valid implementation of the `<cmath>` functions then. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: @Homer512, aha, `res.on.exception.handling` is the kind of thing I was looking for. One can take all the `<math.h>` functions to effectively be `noexcept`. That implies, as far as I can tell, that floating point assignment, comparison, and arithmetic is supposed to be considered non-throwing, at least outside of UB. Thanks so much for that pointer.

Comment: @JanSchultke Note this footnote: 184) That is, the C library functions can all be treated as if they are marked noexcept. This allows implementations to make
performance optimizations based on the absence of exceptions at runtime

Comment: @KristianSpangsege On second thought, the math.h implementation may simply catch any thrown exception and give the corresponding C-like behavior. After all, as long as your platform has a C compiler, you need some floating point implementation that doesn't throw exceptions

Comment: There's a lot of good stuff in these recent comments.  Would you be able to summarise them somehow in the answer, so they don't get lost?  That would be really helpful for future readers.

Comment: @TobySpeight yeah good point, I've incorporated a few things said here in the answer.